# Regex - Renaming file to highest resolution in filename

Tags: regex, file, rename

I'm using an application called Advanced Renamer to rename my video files. I try to rename video files by selecting the highest quality available, which is specified inside the current filename itself.

For example an original untoched filename looks like: `1080P,720P,480P,240P,_123456789.mp4`

Im using regex to rename this example file to: `1080P_123456789.mp4`.

However, the result of the regex I'm using right now `.*(?=1080P|720P|480P|240P)` does not work properly, it's taking the lowest quality instead of the highest: `240P,_123456789.mp4`

Correct examples:

```
1080P,720P,480P,240P,_0987654321.mp4  --> 1080P_0987654321.mp4
720P,480P,_0987654321.mp4             --> 720P_0987654321.mp4
480P,240P,_0987654321.mp4             --> 480P_0987654321.mp4
```

Wrong examplesmy regex is giving me:

```
1080P,720P,480P,240P,_0987654321.mp4  --> 240P_0987654321.mp4
720P,480P,_0987654321.mp4             --> 480P_0987654321.mp4
480P,240P,_0987654321.mp4             --> 240P_0987654321.mp4
```

**Edit: Solution**

```
^.*?(1080P|720P|480P|240P).*?(_\d+\.mp4).*$
OR 
^.*?(\d+P).*?_(\d+\.mp4)\S*
OR
.*?(\d+P)[^.]*_(\d+\.mp4)\S*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `^(1080P|720P|480P|240P).*,(.*)`. The `^` will match the first occurance in the line.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I replied below the answer of @thefourthBird

Comment: I've posted my comment below the answer of @TheFourthBird. Thanks for posting the solution both of you!

Answer (score 1):

For the current example data, you could capture the first occurrence in a capturing group as that is the highest value.

Then match any char except an underscore afterwards using a negated character class followed by an underscore to make sure it is there.

```
\b(\d+P)\b[^_]*_
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(\d+P)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits and `P`
- `\b` Word boundary
- `[^_]*_` Match 0+ times any char except `_`, then match an `_`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ccGgb/1)

In the replacement use the first capturing group followed by the matched underscore which was part of the match and is not present in the capturing group.

---

If you also want to remove what comes before the digits and `P` and after `.mp4` with the specific numbers:

```
^.*?(1080P|720P|480P|240P).*?(_\d+\.mp4).*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I5xEIg/1)

In the replacement use both capturing groups `$1$2`

Comment: Thank you and @eraklon for the replies! Both answer did work but what if there any more characters before the resolution and after the file extension? Then both answers doesn't work so I've tried to mix both regexes to get what I want but without luck. Maybe someone can see what is wrong with this regex because I can't see it. https://regex101.com/r/2ccGgb/5

Comment: @Johanthan Do you mean like this? `.*?(\d+P)[^.]*_(\d+\.mp4)\S*` https://regex101.com/r/JNlOzX/1 Or like this `^.*?(\d+P).*?_(\d+\.mp4)\S*` https://regex101.com/r/GkGuuj/1

Comment: @Johanthan Note that the word boundary `\b` does not match between a digit and an underscore. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much guys, you both posted the correct solution! I've updated my very first post and added the solution. Three of the regex's posted by you guys are working. Thank you so much, also for the quick replies! <3

Comment: Glad we could help! :)